# How can I retrieve data from MySQL table and insert it into QR code using PHP?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql

I have this PHP code that should retrieve data from a MySQL database and embed it into a  a QR code:

```
 <?php
    include(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

$db     = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$user   = JFactory::getUser();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);    
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('Nom', 'Cognoms', 'eCorreu')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_socis'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('Username') . ' = '. $db->quote($user->Username));     
$db->setQuery($query);
$codeContents = $db->loadObjectList();

$data  = $codeContents[0]->Nom;
$data .= $codeContents[0]->Cognoms;
$data .= $codeContents[0]->eCorreu;

$tempDir  = JPATH_SITE . '/images/';   
$fileName = 'qr_'.md5($data).'.png';   
$pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
$urlRelativeFilePath = JUri::root() .'images/' . $fileName;

if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
    QRcode::png($data, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
}       
echo '<img src="'.$urlRelativeFilePath.'" />';
    ?>
```

However, I just get an image icon. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Dani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

Ok I've done a test. I connected to the `#__users` table and pulled the `name` and `username` of the ID of the current logged in user like so:

```
include(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

$db     = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$user   = JFactory::getUser();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);    
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('name', 'username')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__users'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote($user->id));     
$db->setQuery($query);
$codeContents = $db->loadObjectList();

$data  = $codeContents[0]->name;
$data .= $codeContents[0]->username;
  
$tempDir  = JPATH_SITE . '/images/';   
$fileName = 'qr_'.md5($data).'.png';   
$pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
$urlRelativeFilePath = JUri::root() .'images/' . $fileName;

if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
    QRcode::png($data, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
}       
echo '<img src="'.$urlRelativeFilePath.'" />';
```

This created the QRCode. I then scanned it on my phone and it displayed the correct data.
So in your case, change the dtabase table name to whatever you wish and type in the fields you want to get from that table.

```
array('name', 'username') // Add what you want here
```

Then you need to define them like so:

```
$data .= $codeContents[0]->NAME_OF_FIELD;
```

You will see a `.` (dot) before the `=`(equals) symbol. This needs to be done for all of them apart from the first one as shown on my code.

Hope this helps

Comment: I cannot check it right now, but I've been studying the code. So then, I would write $codeContents = $results to pass this information into the QR code?

Comment: @DaniValverde - I've updated my answer with some more code which loops through all the results and applies them to the QR

Comment: You're awsome Lodder. I'll try it when I'm back at home. Thanks

Comment: I've tried your code, but I get a MySQL error. Check my updated question for details.

Comment: Table doesnt exist? Are you sure you you need to get the data from that table?

Comment: You're right, I misspelled it. Now I get no error nut only an image icon. See my code in my updated question.

Comment: @DaniValverde - tested an updated my answer. Copy and paste this code exactly for the first test. Then read the rest of my answer ;)

Comment: I'm getting crazy. I've done exactly what you told me to do, but I only get an icon image. See my updated question for the exact code.

Comment: @DaniValverde - change `$user->Username` to `$user->username`. Lowercase `u`. Then make sure you are logged in ;)

Comment: Great! This is working now! I've learned quite a lot of thinks, today. Thank you so much! If you ever come to Catalonia or I come to UK, I owe quite a lot of beers ;)

Comment: Haha, you're welcome, glad it's working :) Also be sure to mark the answer as solved ;)

Comment: The alias for `quote()` and `quoteName()` methods are `q()` and `qn()` respectively.